# Passing an object to a superclass in Java

Tags: java, super

For an assignment I'm supposed to have a constructor that takes name, address, phone, make, model, capacity, and numAxles as arguments. The first five should be passed to the superclass, Vehicle. The UML says that my superclass should take the object "person" as the first argument (which is from another class and takes name, address, and phone). How do I pass as argument the name, address, and phone to the superclass from the Truck constructor?

Here's the [UML](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PZWFS.png)

The Truck class

```
public Truck(Person person, String make, String model, int year, int mileage, int capacity, int numAxles){
        super(person, make, model, year, mileage);

    }

    public Truck(String name, String address, String phone, String make, String model, int capacity, int numAxles ){
        super(name, address, phone, make, model);
    }
```

The Vehicle superclass

```
public Vehicle(Person person, String make, String model, int year){
        setMileage(0);
    }
```

Comment: Does your class actually extend `Vehicle`?

Comment: yeah the class header is:

public class Truck extends Vehicle{

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by constrcuting a new `Person`

```
super(new Person(name, address, phone), make, model, 2020);
```

You will probably need some default number for the year as you have not provided it.

Comment: Alternately, `Vehicle` needs a ctor that does not require a `Person`, or you can just pass `null` in for the person.  This all depends on requirements so it's a little hard to guess what is actually needed.  Many ways to do it.

Comment: @markspace Yep, it is a bit of a guess, but seeing as there are variables such as `name` `address` etc, I took a wild guess and assumed that these were part of a `Person`

Comment: It's a good guess, I just wanted to provide the OP with some alternatives in case one was actually what they needed.

Comment: @AbhijitSarkar The link that you gave did not answer the question.  If you can find a duplicate then close this question.

Comment: [how to call superclass constructor java](https://www.google.com/search?q=how+to+call+superclass+constructor+java&oq=How+to+call+superclass&aqs=chrome.2.0i457j69i57j0l6.5658j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8). Don't get me wrong, you spent the time answering his question, but he failed to show any effort of having tried.

Comment: @AbhijitSarkar I am guessing that you do not understand the question (as vague as it was).  The issue is not just with calling `super`, it is creating a new `Object` - normally a Noob may try to create that Object then pass that Object to `super`, but this would be invalid code.  - Do you understand now?